# Print requested lines from multiple files

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to get specific lines from multiple files.

I tried doing this:

```
sed -n "5p;10p" file1.txt file2.txt
```

but it only prints lines from the first file, does anyone have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: `sed` doesn't differentiate multiple files and considers them all as one stream.

Comment: @karakfa : ouch, never ran into that. As usual, there **is** an awk solution ;-) Removing my previous comment. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==5 || FNR==10' file{1,2}.txt
```

will print 5th and 10th lines from both files.

Or, every 5th line, easily (5,10,15,...)

```
$ awk '!(FNR%5)' file{1,2}.txt
```

Or, the prime number lines

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=sqrt(NR);i++) if(!(NR%i)) next} NR>1' file{1,2}.txt
```

As a variation of the last script, this is a more optimized version

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(p in ps) if(!(NR%p)) next; ps[NR]; print}'
```

Here is another one, more verbose but optimized

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {f=1} 
       NR>1  {if(NR==(f+1)^2) f++; 
              for(i=0; i<c && ps[i]<=f; i++) if(!(NR%ps[i])) next; 
              ps[c++]=NR; print}'
```

you can eliminate square calculation as well.

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN {f=1; ns=4} 
        NR>1  {if(NR==ns) ns+=2*(++f)+1; 
               for(i=0; i<c && ps[i]<=f; i++) if(!(NR%ps[i])) next; 
               ps[c++]=NR; print}'
```

Comment: @karafa : i used ur basic framework and squeezed out another **`9.497 %`** time savings. see post below

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GNU sed you can use the `-s` switch. From the manual:

```
'-s' '--separate'
     By default, 'sed' will consider the files specified on the command
     line as a single continuous long stream.  This GNU 'sed' extension
     allows the user to consider them as separate files: range
     addresses (such as '/abc/,/def/') are not allowed to span several
     files, line numbers are relative to the start of each file, '$'
     refers to the last line of each file, and files invoked from the
     'R' commands are rewound at the start of each file.
```

Comment: Neat, I did not know this! For those on OSX, you can install gnu-sed with homebrew and access it as `gsed`.

Comment: It is worth knowing that the `-i` switch uses `-s` switch _behind the scenes_.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `sed` is concatenating those files before processing them. Try something like this:

```
for f in file1.txt file2.txt; do
    sed -n "5p;10p" $f
done
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines,that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. This problem is not a simple substitution on an individual line and therefore you should not be using sed, you should be using awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(lines,tmp,/,/)
    for (i in tmp) {
        split(tmp[i],range,/-/)
        j = range[1]
        do {
            fnrs[j]
        } while (j++<range[2])
    }
}
FNR in fnrs { print FILENAME, FNR, $0 }

$ paste file1 file2
a       A
b       B
c       C
d       D
e       E
f       F
g       G

$ awk -v lines="2,4-6" -f tst.awk file1 file2
file1 2 b
file1 4 d
file1 5 e
file1 6 f
file2 2 B
file2 4 D
file2 5 E
file2 6 F
```

Answer (score 0):

sed:

```
for f in file1.txt file2.txt; do
    sed -n "5p;10p" $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution for printing **prime numbered lines**, built on top of the basic framework that **`@karakfa`** has shown in his post above :

```
mawk2 'BEGIN {
    _^=_-=____=_+=_+=\
    _______=______=_^=split(_="",_____)
} {
    ______+=____<(\
    ____+=(____==(___=NR) ? _+______*++_+_ :!++_))
    if (___<=+_) {
        _=_==___
    } else if (___ < ((_+_)*++_)) {
        _=___!=_^--_ && ___%_
    } else if ( (!+(((__=___ % (_^_+_)) %_)\
                   *(__%(_+--_))*(__%_) )) ||
                (!+(((__=___ % (++_^++_-_)\
                ) % (_+(_+=_--)))*(__%_)))) {
        _-=_
    } else {
        for(_+=(_+=_^=_<_)+_;_____[_]<=______;_++) {
            if (!(___%_____[_] ) ) { _-=_
                break } } _=-_<+_ }
    if (!+_) { _=!_; next } } _____[++_______]=___'
```

- benchmarking for all prime numbered lines up to half a million,

  ```
   09/25/22 ::: 19:59:34 ( 1664150374.549211 )
   09/25/22 ::: 19:59:35 ( 1664150375.040526 )

   out9:  273KiB 0:00:00 [ 586KiB/s] [ 586KiB/s] [ <=> ]
   ( jot 500000 | mawk2 ; )
  ```

> `0.56s user 0.01s system 118% cpu` **`0.486 total`**
>
> `0f9b06f36afeff97a5eb56a9dc9073da stdin`

- **`@karakfa`**'s original code - only changing executing `awk` variant to be same `mawk2`,

  ```
   09/25/22 ::: 19:59:35 ( 1664150375.555522 )
   09/25/22 ::: 19:59:36 ( 1664150376.097916 )

   out9:  273KiB 0:00:00 [ 527KiB/s] [ 527KiB/s] [ <=> ]
   ( jot 500000 | mawk2 ; )
  ```

> `0.61s user 0.01s system 116% cpu` **`0.537 total`**
>
> `0f9b06f36afeff97a5eb56a9dc9073da stdin`

Comment: Impressive but I guess you missed the lecture on *"Programs are meant to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute."*

Comment: @karakfa: i only got `A-` in that course that was all about `SML` and code elegance, so there's that - but there's nothing all that special about my "optimizations" other than adding in upfront hard-coded filters for `2, 3, 5, 7, 11`, which helps weed out the vast majority of test cases before running it through the `for` loop that has been updated to directly commence at `index = 6th prime aka 13` instead of the beginning - nothing fancy

Comment: @karakfa : as for my programming style, this example i uploaded (https://i.imgur.com/eT44hPp.png) hopefully would illustrate why it's actually easier to read it at the high level - because there's only 1 single letter in this underscore alphabet (i.e. "base 1"), no 2 variables can even share the same length in its name, thus, for a piece of repetitive code like that, one can zoom really far out and still see the structure of it, and quickly detect any typos, since mis-placed variable means the line would be suddenly not the expected length as its peers, something that's easy to spot visually

Comment: Not trying to convince you but there is a reason why some of the ancient number systems didn't scale: e.g. I II III IIII  up to IIIIIIIII, so a compact representation as digits had a better fit. At one point the you will to be focusing the number underscores instead of abstract concept of the algorithm.  Might be fun exercise for a one-liner, but that's probably the limit for me.

Comment: @karakfa : exactly how many variables u need inside a single function for "scaling" to start coming into play ?

Comment: Depends on your memory skills. For me up to 5 is fine and definitely more than 7 is difficult to keep track.  However, this is not just to number of variables, but the markings of them. If you start counting underscores to figure out which is which then it's a problem.

The fundamental issue I'm trying to argue is: sites like this are meant to be educational. If no one else can read your code let alone learn from it, what is the purpose of you posting here?

Comment: @karakfa : that's fine by me - i'm not here seeking communal praise