# Printing nth rows after a row number in awk

Tags: awk, printing, conditional-statements

```
    1,A
    2,B
    3,C
    4,D
    5,E
    6,F
    7,G
    8,H
    9,I
   10,J
   11,K
   12,L
   13,M
   14,N
```

How do I print row 4 first and then the 9th row and then the 14th row using awk? I want to first print the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row, until the end of the file.
I tried this:

```
awk '{if(NR==4 || (NR>4 && NR==NR+7)) print $0}' file
```

But this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

The output should be:

```
4,D
9,I
14,N
```

Comment: Is that what you want: `awk 'NR%5 == 4'` ?

Comment: Regarding `and then the 14th row` - make sure your example contains at least 14 rows so we can test a potential solution.

Comment: print every 5th row (starting with NR==4) until end of file

Comment: Simply `awk 'NR==4 || NR==9 || NR==14'` will do literally what you are asking. If there is a more basic generalization you want to implement, please explain it.

Comment: Could "starting with `NR==4`" ever be starting with some other line number? If so could that number every be greater than 5?

Comment: Let's try this another way - is your question truly `I want to firs print the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row` as you stated or is it the simpler `I want to print the 4th row out of every 5 rows`? The output would be the same either way if you always want to start at the 4th row, but it'd be different if you might want to start at the 9th or some other row, and so it'd take a different solutions for each requirement.

Comment: That's a good point. For now what I want to do is what I wrote exactly. What you said is worth thinking and I will work on that and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to print every 5th line starting from a specific line number:

```
$ seq 20 | awk 'NR==4{c=4} c && !((++c) % 5)'
4
9
14
19

$ seq 20 | awk 'NR==2{c=4} c && !((++c) % 5)'
2
7
12
17

$ seq 20 | awk 'NR==6{c=4} c && !((++c) % 5)'
6
11
16
```

`c && !((++c) % 5)` says:

> If `c` is set then increment `c` and test if that new value modulo
> `5` is zero.

So no line before `NR==4` can be printed as `c` is never populated before that happens, and then when `c` is set to 4, it's then increment to `5` and `5 % 5` is `0` so the line is printed. `c` gets incremented for every line after that and so `c % 5` continually rotates through `1 2 3 4 0` thus printing every 5th line when `0` occurs and so `!0` is true.

To do the above using values set on the command line rather than hard-coded in the script would be:

```
$ seq 20 | awk -v b=4 -v n=5 'NR==b{c=n-1} c && !((++c) % n)'
4
9
14
19
```

---

EDIT - here's why [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829899/printing-nth-rows-after-a-row-number-in-awk/73829940?noredirect=1#comment130366892_73829899):

> is your question truly `I want to firs print the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row` as you stated or is
> it the simpler `I want to print the 4th row out of every 5 rows`?

to which [the OP replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829899/printing-nth-rows-after-a-row-number-in-awk/73829940?noredirect=1#comment130367270_73829899)

> what I want to do is what I wrote exactly

and the difference between the possible solutions to THAT problem when you generalize to be able to change "4th" to some other number, e.g. "6th":

> I want to firs print the 6th row and then continue printing every 5th
> row after the 6th row

```
$ seq 20 | awk 'NR==6{c=4} c && !((++c) % 5)'
6
11
16

$ seq 20 | awk 'NR%5==6'
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works. Appreciate it. I can understand from NR==4{c=4} c, here you are creating a variable and assigning it a value 4 correct. In the and condition are you saying, !((++c) % 5, increment after 4 is not a factor of 5? Please let me know.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: he just needs `awk 'NR%5==4' file`

Comment: @karakfa not if he wants to print every 5th row starting at some row numer `b` as I stated. He used b=4 as an example and you can do `awk 'NR%5==b'` as long as `b` is less than 5, but not if it's greater than or equal to 5. I asked the OP in comments under the question which he meant and he said that `I want to firs print the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row` rather than `I want to print the 4th row out of every 5 rows`.

Comment: See [the comment I just added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829899/printing-nth-rows-after-a-row-number-in-awk/73829940?noredirect=1#comment130372906_73830072) under M.NejatAydin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
awk 'NR%5 == 4' file
```

will do the job.
Alternatively, if you have GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n 4~5p file
```

---

**Edit:**
A general solution to the problem of printing every *n*th line starting with line *s* using `awk` could be, for example, like that:

```
awk -v s=6 -v n=5 'NR>=s && NR%n == s%n' file
```

(`s%n` could be precomputed and assigned to a variable.)

But using GNU `sed` would be much simpler for this task:

```
sed -n "${s}~${n}p" file
```

where `s` and `n` are shell variables (their values must be positive integers).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified my question and stated clearly what I want. This answer is helpful if I was trying to print the 4th row out of every 5 rows. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Process1 You wrote `"I want to first print the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row, until the end of the file."`. The code above does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Process1 And, I really don't understand what the difference is between `"printing the 4th row out of every 5 rows"` and `"printing the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row"`.

Comment: both are good and right solutions for posted problem.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin change `4th` to `6th` everywhere in the OPS problem statement, "I want to first print the 4th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 4th row, until the end of the file.", so it becomes "I want to first print the 6th row and then continue printing every 5th row after the 6th row, until the end of the file." and then try implementing that by changing `awk 'NR%5 == 4' file` to `awk 'NR%5 == 6' file`

Comment: @EdMorton that's a what-if, the wording is most likely not understanding the fundamental problem or language skills (inclusive or). Similarly you can what-if, start at 6, then every 5th row, then 6th row etc. Even in your what-if, `sed` is probably a better solution. `awk` is better for complicated cases, for example to print prime numbered lines `awk '{for(i=2;i<=sqrt(NR);i++) if(!(NR%i)) next} NR>1'`

Comment: @karakfa, no, it's a "what-the-OP-said". That's why I specifically asked the OP what they meant and [their response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829899/printing-nth-rows-after-a-row-number-in-awk/73830072?noredirect=1#comment130367270_73829899) certainly makes me think they understand the difference. If you think there's a better sed solution then of course you should post it.

Comment: I can read that's what he literally said, what I meant the interpretation of it. You're treating whether the initial 4 is a special case instead of being part of the overall pattern. Regardless, `sed -n 6~5p` would do your what-if as well. Simple solutions for simple problems. The OP not being able to abstract the general case might be the cause why he can't find the solution without help.

*The formulation of a problem is often more essential than its solution which may be merely a matter of mathematical or experimental skill.* **- Albert Einstein**

Comment: Re "You're treating whether the initial 4 is a special case instead of being part of the overall pattern." right because I specifically asked the OP and they said that's what they wanted and it is the answer to the problem stated in the subject line `Printing nth rows after a row number in awk` which others in future will find when searching the archives for an answer to that problem. The solution to the problem of `Printing nth rows after a row number in awk` is NOT `'NR%n == x'` for any values of n and x such that x>=n.

Comment: @karakfa : if i'm understanding it correctly, ur prime numbered lines suggestion would involve calling `sqrt( )` once for each increment of `i` when it easily could be computed just once per NR, plus it seems to also treat each `NR` as a brand new prime number search when it probably could be done more like a sequential sieve   ?

Comment: @EdMorton you're right for future reference. I wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto right, not optimal. Some compilers do this optimization for you but probably not awk. Regardless, it was a showcase for feature not speed.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto here is an optimized version of the prime number sequence https://stackoverflow.com/a/34427798/1435869 fresh out of oven.

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin Thanks for the post. This helps. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` solution

```
$ seq 30 | awk -v b=14 -v n=5 'NR>=b && !((NR-b)%n)'
14
19
24
29
```

this is just the translation of `sed -n 14~5p`.

Comment: Thanks @karakfa. Appreciate the post. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
awk '{if(NR==4 || (NR>4 && NR==NR+7)) print $0}' file
```

contain condition `NR==NR+7` which does never hold, in turn what is right to `||` is always false and therefore your code is in fact acting like it would be

```
awk '{if(NR==4) print $0}' file
```

> print row 4 first and then the 9th row and then the 14th row using
> awk?

Just provide GNU `AWK` with `;`-sheared conditions describing lines you want that is

```
awk 'NR==4;NR==9;NR==14' file
```

Keep in mind that altering order does *not* change output, so you will get same output for

```
awk 'NR==14;NR==9;NR==4' file
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: `awk 'NR==4;NR==9;NR==14' file` = `awk 'NR~/^(4|9|14)$/' file`, saves duplicating `NR==` each time which could become a pain if your input file is more than 18 lines long and you want to enumerate every 5th input line that way.

Answer (score -1):

- doing it in `awk` without ever using `modulo %` :

> ```
> jot 30 | mawk 'BEGIN { __+=_+=_+=__=_^=FS="^$" } _-(_+=__*(_==NR))'
> ```

```
4
9
14
19
24
29
```

- generic solution without `modulo %` :

  -- `"1st print` ***`17th`*** `row then once every`  ***`29`*** `rows after that"`

> ```
> jot 200 | gawk '__-(__+=___*(NR == __))' FS='^$' __=17 ___=29
> ```

```
17
46
75
104
133
162
191
```

- extremely succinct way if u only want odd-numbered rows :

> ```
> jot 14 | nawk '_*=--_'
> ```

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
```

Comment: these are crazy! The last one can be shortened to `awk '_=!_'`

Comment: @karakfa : why is a solution that avoids expensive `modulo %` "crazy" in your eyes ? but dang the last proposal is a good one i haven't thought of … i'm surprised why people keep doing `NR % 2` - compilers obviously optimize it into a bitwise AND, but i'm not aware of `awk` doing that … does it ?

Comment: `NR%2` requires a special case optimization trick, similar to division or multiplication by 2. I don't think `awk` is doing either.

Comment: see my version to accommodate arbitrary starting position and step size. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73847409/1435869

Comment: @karakfa : original question was easier cuz the starting point is lower than the modulo cycle length - if it's larger, the shortcut approach fails, by definition of what a modulo is :  `jot 50 | mawk '(NR%29)==17'` gets you `17` and `46` but `jot 50 | mawk '(NR%17)==29'` prints absolutely nothing, whereas my solution works for both scenarios as long as the inputs are positive integers

Comment: @karakfa : yes i just saw it - it requires checking ***every single*** `NR` whether it's at least initial row, plus a per row operation combo of expensive modulo (aka `"remainder after division"`) `("%")`, logical negate `("!")` and logical AND `("&&")`. I don't see how that's a better approach that one that only requires one each of numerical compare `("==")` and these low-cost algebraic operations `"+="` `"—"`  `" x "`

Comment: boolean operations are not expensive (`&&` and `!`). Modulo is not either a%b = a - (a/b)b, where division is integer division.  It's marginally more expensive than any other numerical operation. However, on GPU it's surprisingly slower. In real life scenarios these theoretical performance concerns are not valid for 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @karakfa : …. that's true …. except that this is `awk` … other than `gmp`, does it actually `true integer types`, e.g. `int64`, division,  or merely simulated via `IEEE 754` `double`-precision floating point ? if it's the latter….. . As for boolean ops - the ops themselves are cheap, but inaccurate branching predictions are costly.

Comment: @karakfa : even `gawk-gmp` isn't consistent : `gawk -Mbe 'BEGIN { ____ = ( __ = _ += _ += _^= _ < _ )^--_-_*_ ; _____ = __ *= __ += __--; __=int( _ = 1. ); while( ___++<____ ) { _ += _++; __ += __++; if ( _____ < ___ ) { print ___, _, __ } } }'`

Comment: `50 2251799813685247 2251799813685247` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`51 4503599627370495 4503599627370495` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`52 9007199254740991 9007199254740991` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`53 18014398509481984 18014398509481983` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`54 36028797018963968 36028797018963967` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`55 72057594037927936 72057594037927935`

Comment: @karakfa : the inception of `"_"` and `"__"` both came from the same `1.`, difference being, for `"__"` an `int( )` call was made at the start, but otherwise, it's numeric ONE. A decimal point alone shouldn't denote existence of fractional digits, and thus, shouldn't be treated as a floating point constant, but yet that's exactly how `gawk-gmp` sees it, and thus, 2 identical pieces of simplistic code that sequentially print out `2^(n + 1) - 1` without using power operator within the loop itself diverges exactly the moment it went past the precision of a `double` type.