How to turn this piped command into a single Awk invocation?
I am formatting an input file, here is a sample of it:
                 The First 1,000,000 Primes





         2         3         5         7        11        13        17        19 


        23        29        31        37        41        43        47        53 


And this file, with the xxd command:
00000000: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000010: 2054 6865 2046 6972 7374 2031 2c30 3030   The First 1,000
00000020: 2c30 3030 2050 7269 6d65 7320 2866 726f  ,000 Primes (fro
00000030: 6d20 7072 696d 6573 2e75 746d 2e65 6475  m primes.utm.edu
00000040: 290d 0d0a 0d0d 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020  )......         
00000050: 3220 2020 2020 2020 2020 3320 2020 2020  2         3     
00000060: 2020 2020 3520 2020 2020 2020 2020 3720      5         7 
00000070: 2020 2020 2020 2031 3120 2020 2020 2020         11       
00000080: 2031 3320 2020 2020 2020 2031 3720 2020   13        17   
00000090: 2020 2020 2031 3920 0d0d 0a20 2020 2020       19 ...     

I am using the command:
awk -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1}1' inputfile

But I get empty lines that I would like to get rid of:
The
First
1,000,000
Primes

2
3
5

I can get rid of it with a pipe:
awk -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1}1' inputfile | awk '!/\r/'

Is there a way to achieve the same by calling Awk only once?

please update the question with a small sample file (3-4 lines, 1-2 'empty' lines) and the complete output from xxd filename

I can't repro. printf 'fnord\r\r\nfoo\r\r\n' | awk -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1; print $1}' | xxd shows that the \r characters are still present.

print $1 will obviously only print the first field; if your lines have subsequent fields which you want to keep, that won't work.

About the \r\r\n, they are revealed by the od -c command

by itself \r\r does not introduce 'empty' lines; printf 'ab\r\r\ncd\r\r\n produces 2 lines of output with no 'empty' lines; your textual description and your code samples are confusing hence the request for a sample file (see my first comment)

I'm not sure i can provide you a sample : as \r\r\n gives the same as if the lines terminate with only \n.

you can show the visual copy of the file (that displays 'empty' lines)  AND the complete xxd output; with the complete xxd output we can use xxd -r (on our machines) to reproduce an exact copy of your file

also, update the question to clarify if you want to maintain the \r\r characters on non-empty lines, or do you want to remove all \r characters?

Ok, i just edited the all post

your 2nd awk script removes blank lines AND the line Primes; do you really want to remove Primes?

I don't see what more is getting removed. In the end i just want a file with all those primes, ordered, one by line. (i will sed -i '1d' the firsts lines)

the first set of data (visual display) does not match with the od -c output (the latter contains the string ' from primes.utm.edu)' as well as a different set of primes), regardless ...  the 2nd awk script, in addition to removing the 'empty' line, is also removing the last field from the first line (Primes in the case of your visual output, primes.utm.edu) in the case of the od -c version of your file)

once you bring awk into the mix there's (usually) no need for sed soooo, update the question (again) to show the expected output; if you want to display only the prime numbers then state this in the question and show it in your expected results

Please [edit] your question to show the exact output you expect from the sample input you provided.

As such, this is already a huge improvement over your original post; thanks.

Though going forward, please take care to not wreck formatting fixes contributed by others when editing.

Assumptions/Understandings:

we do not need to maintain the \r characters
(per comment from) OP only wants to display the prime numbers (one per line)

Reconstituting OP's file from the xxd output:
$ xxd -r <<< '00000000: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000010: 2054 6865 2046 6972 7374 2031 2c30 3030   The First 1,000
00000020: 2c30 3030 2050 7269 6d65 7320 2866 726f  ,000 Primes (fro
00000030: 6d20 7072 696d 6573 2e75 746d 2e65 6475  m primes.utm.edu
00000040: 290d 0d0a 0d0d 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020  )......         
00000050: 3220 2020 2020 2020 2020 3320 2020 2020  2         3     
00000060: 2020 2020 3520 2020 2020 2020 2020 3720      5         7 
00000070: 2020 2020 2020 2031 3120 2020 2020 2020         11       
00000080: 2031 3320 2020 2020 2020 2031 3720 2020   13        17   
00000090: 2020 2020 2031 3920 0d0d 0a20 2020 2020       19 ...' > inputfile

Tweaking OP's current awk script:
awk -v OFS="\n" '
NR==1 { next }                      # skip 1st line
      { gsub(/\r/,"" )              # strip all "\r" characters from line
        $1=$1
      }
length()                            # if resulting line length > 0 then print to stdout
' inputfile

#### as a one-liner:

awk -v OFS="\n" 'NR==1{next}{gsub(/\r/,""); $1=$1} length()' inputfile

An alternative awk idea:
awk 'NR>1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)     # skip 1st line and loop through all fields
                if ($i+0==$i)       # if the field is a number (prime in this case) then ...
                    print $i        # print on its own line
          }
' inputfile

#### as a one-liner:

awk 'NR>1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0==$i) print $i}' inputfile

These both generates:
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19


Without expected output it's a guess but is this what you're trying to do?
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '/^[[:space:]0-9]+$/{$1=$1; print}' file
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53

or maybe this?
$ awk '/^[[:space:]0-9]+$/{$1=$1; printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=OFS} END{print ""}' file
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53

They'll both behave the same way with any POSIX awk.

Even grep -Eo '[0-9]+' would approximate what you seem to be looking for, but then you have to filter out the digits from 1,000,000 in the title separately. With grep -o '[1-9][0-9]* you're already pretty close, though it picks up the 1 from 1,000,000. But we can remove that line separately, since we know it's always the first line:
grep -o '[1-9][0-9]*' inputfile | tail -n +2

If you wanted to keep the first line in its entirety, but with whitespace trimmed,
grep -o -m1 '[^[:space:]].*[^[:space:]]' inputfile
grep -o '[1-9][0-9]*' inputfile | tail -n +2

Obviously, with the pipe to tail, this is not a single process either way; but if your input data is dirty like this, you should probably clean it up once, and then use the results going forward.
Exploring the URL in the first line of the file, it now redirects to a different site. On there, I find https://t5k.org/lists/small/1000.txt which is somewhat more regular than your example, although it still contains DOS line endings. It's weird that the site doesn't provide the list in machine-readable form. There are other sites which do; though for example, https://primes.org/swagger-ui/index.html seems a bit too mechanical (you'd have to call the API for each prime you want!) https://sethriedel.com/primes/api/docs.html accepts a single API call to specify a range, and produces a result in JSON form which is perhaps easier to work with.
curl -s https://sethriedel.com/primes/api/primes.php?limit=123 |
jq -r '.primes | .[]' >primes.txt


another approach is with a script almost the same size of formatting you can generate the primes
$ awk -v N=1000 'BEGIN{print 2; c++; 
                       for(i=3;c<N;i+=2) 
                         {b=0; 
                          for(p in ps) if(!(i%p)) {b=1; break}; 
                          if(b) continue; 
                          ps[i]; c++; print i}}'

slight optimization to skip even numbers.
$ awk -v N=10 ...

will generate first 10 primes
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29

few other variations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34427798/1435869

The default print-if-true property of AWK can be used to remove 'blank' lines, like this:
awk -v OFS="\n"  '{$1=$1} $0!=""' file

The condition returns 1 or 0 depending on the content of the line. 1 causes default print behaviour, 0 skips printing. $0!="" returns true only if the output line is non-empty.
Output:
The
First
1,000,000
Primes
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53

(I didn't deal with formatting the title line(s) as you don't ask, and it's trivial).

make that - awk NF=NF OFS='\n', which also skips the empty lines

@RAREKpopManifesto that's neat. What is NF=NF doing here? I've not come across that before and can't yet understand why it works.

NF=NF is just a much more succinct way of saying '{$1=$1} $0!=""' - they're identical in operations performed (as well as rows selected for output), cuz totally empty lines would have NF == 0, so assigning zero back into itself makes the "pattern" zero, i.e. false, thus no printing will ensue. It's even better because $1=$1 requires at least 1 pair of single quotes around it, while NF=NF is totally console-safe unquoted.

awk ~ RS='(^.*[[:alpha:]])?[[:space:]]+'


2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53

